# Number of metrics allowed in Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: python, google-analytics-4

I'm not able to find any (official) documentation saying what's the limit on the number of metrics that can be queried within the same API call. Out of the developer tool (https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/) I can tell that the limit is 10, however I can't tell if this limit is coming from the API (Python) or from the developer interface available. Can someone, please, confirm and share the reference to the appropriated doc, if any. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to find this :

[Document : Metric](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/Metric?hl=en)

So yes it is from Data API limit.

```
The quantitative measurements of a report. 
For example, the metric eventCount is the total number of events. 
Requests are allowed up to 10 metrics.
```